# How to wait until all images have loaded before running Cypress test?

Tags: cypress, cypress-conditional-testing, percy

I have a Nextjs project that is using Percy (with Cypress integration) to run visual tests. My project fetches images from a CMS. How can I make sure all images on the page have loaded before (taking the snapshot) or checking elements?

I have seen an example that checks for broken images

```
const brokenImages = []
cy.get('img')
  .each(($el, k) => {
    if ($el.prop('naturalWidth') === 0) {
      const id = $el.attr('id')
      const alt = $el.attr('alt')
      const info = `${id ? '#' + id : ''} ${alt ? alt : ''}`
      brokenImages.push(info)
      cy.log(`Broken image ${k + 1}: ${info}`)
    }
  })
  .then(() => {
    // report all broken images at once
    // enable the condition to see the thrown error
    if (false && brokenImages.length) {
      throw new Error(
        `Found ${
          brokenImages.length
        } broken images\n${brokenImages.join(', ')}`,
      )
    }
  })
```

and another one that checks a single image's natural width (which doesn't work in Nextjs

```
cy.get('#loads')
  .should('be.visible')
  .and('have.prop', 'naturalWidth')
  .should('be.greaterThan', 0)
```

Am I going to have to just wait a set number of seconds and hope they have loaded?

Comment: BTW `if (false && ...)` looks like it would always be false (the error never be thrown)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The property `naturalWidth` is native to javascript and should not be affected by the NextJs framework,
i.e any `<img>` on a running web page should return a non-zero naturalWidth property.

However, the images may be lazy-loaded in which case `.scrollIntoView()` may fix your problem.

I ran this test on a selection of Nextjs sample pages and they all passed

```js
describe('nextjs img loading examples', () => {

  const sites = [
    'https://image-component.nextjs.gallery/',
    'https://app-router-contentful.vercel.app/',
    'https://next-blog-prismic.vercel.app/',
    'https://next-blog-umbraco-heartcore.vercel.app/'
  ]

  sites.forEach(site => {
    it(`verifies images for ${site}`, () => {
      cy.visit(site);
      cy.get('img').each(img => {
        cy.wrap(img)
          .scrollIntoView()
          .its('0.naturalWidth')   // Note "0" extracts element from jQuery wrapper
          .should('be.greaterThan', 0)
      })
    })
  })
})
```

[image]

---

#### Have the images loaded?

According to the examples by Gleb Bahmutov [Cypress examples (v13.6.5) - Image Has Loaded](https://glebbahmutov.com/cypress-examples/recipes/image-loaded.html) (the source for your first code block)

> To check if an image has successfully loaded, check its property naturalWidth.
> It is **only set if the browser downloaded and displayed the image**.

Based on Gleb's code - adding a delay to the first image we can demo with simple before/after screenshots

**HTML**

```html
<img
  id="img1"
  src=""
  width="400"
  height="50"
  alt="Warming stripes"
/>
<img
  id="img3"
  width="40"
  height="40"
  src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4
  //8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
  alt="red dot"
/>
<script>
  setTimeout(() => {
    const img = document.getElementById('img1')
    img.src = 'https://glebbahmutov.com/images/warming-stripes.png'
  }, 3000)
</script>
```

**Test**

```js
cy.screenshot('before')
cy.get('img').each(img => {
  cy.wrap(img)
    .scrollIntoView()
    .its('0.naturalWidth')
    .should('be.greaterThan', 0)
})
cy.screenshot('after')
```

**"Before" screenshot - img1 has not yet loaded**

[image]

**"After" screenshot - img1 has loaded**

### [image]

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you. How do I wait for all images to load before performing the assertion? In my case I want to take a snapshot cy.percySnapshot() only after all images have loaded

Comment: According to the example for broken images you cited, `naturalWidth` is the way to wait for the images to load.

Comment: The code `cy.get('img').each(img => ...` should wait for every image to load, provided there is an `<img>` element for every image on the page as received from `cy.visit()`, which usually should be the case for NextJs since it is server rendered.

Comment: However, you might want to add a count assertion for the `<img>` tags - `cy.get('img').should('have.length', 6).each( img => ...` to make sure you check the correct  number of images.